# How to concatenate several Float32Array arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to concatenate several Float32Array arrays?

For example:

```
var a = new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]);
var b = new Float32Array([4, 5, 6]);
var c = new Float32Array([7, 8, 9]);
//concat code here
var res = ...
res
Float32Array(9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this in ES6

```
var a = new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]);
var b = new Float32Array([4, 5, 6]);
var c = new Float32Array([7, 8, 9]);
var res = new Float32Array([...a, ...b, ...c])
```